# AS3: BitmapData linked to certain sprite in library?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, background, sprite, bitmapdata

I have a problem. I have a sprite added to library and I linked and named its class "CarriedHead_Normal". Now I want to display this sprite and make every black(000000) pixel invisible (just convert background to alpha).

I know I can use this

```
 var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0x000000)
```

But how am I supposed to merge this with my function, so I call the class from the library and make it's bg transparent?

My current code:

```
 var imageSprite = new Sprite();
 addChild(imageSprite);



 var libraryImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new CarriedHead_Normal(0, 0))

 imageSprite.addChild(libraryImage);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var libraryImage:Bitmap = spriteToBitmap(new CarriedHead_Normal());
imageSprite.addChild(libraryImage);

function spriteToBitmap(sprite:Sprite, smoothing:Boolean = false):Bitmap
{
   var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height, true, 0x00000000);
   bitmapData.draw(sprite);
   bitmapData.threshold(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, new Point(), '==', 0xff000000, 0x00000000);
   return new Bitmap(bitmapData, "auto", smoothing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A number of ways you could do it, some working better than others:

*On a side node, your question title has nothing to do with your actual question*

1) **Use blend modes**

Depending on your graphics and background, you might be able to get away with a simple `blendMode` - check out `BlendMode.SCREEN` in particular. Note that some blend modes require that your parent container have a `blendMode` of `BlendMode.LAYER`

2) **copyPixels() using an alpha BMD**

`copyPixels()` lets you specify an alpha `BitmapData` to use when deciding which pixels to copy over (actually the alpha value of the pixels to copy over). If you have an alpha `BitmapData` that matches your black areas, you can remove it like that:

```
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData( myImageBMD.width, myImageBMD.height, true, 0x00000000 );
b.copyPixels( myImageBMD, myImageBMD.rect, new Point, alphaBMD, new Point, false ); // copy our image, using alphaBMD to remove the black
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()

3) **floodFill() the black areas**

If your black area is continuous and you know a pixel that it starts on (e.g. it's a black frame around an image), then you can use `floodFill()` to remove the black areas

```
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData( myImageBMD.width, myImageBMD.height, true, 0x00000000 );
b.copyPixels( myImageBMD, myImageBMD.rect, new Point ); // copy our image so we keep the original
b.floodFill( 0, 0, 0x00000000 ); // assuming the first pixel is black, floodFill() from here, replacing with transparence
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill()

This technique will work best on pixel art, where the edges are well defined.

4) **threshold() to remove the black**

`threshold()` takes pixel values and replaces them with the value you set if they pass a certain test (`<`, `<=`, `==`, etc). You can use this to replace black with transparence.

```
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData( myImageBMD.width, myImageBMD.height, true, 0x00000000 );
b.copyPixels( myImageBMD, myImageBMD.rect, new Point ); // copy our image so we keep the original
b.threshold( b, b.rect, new Point, "==", 0xff000000, 0x00000000 ); // test the pixels; if they're black, replace with transparence
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold()

Again, this works best when the edges are well defined.

5) **Use filters**

You can use `applyFilter()` to create a new image, using a `BitmapFilter` to remove the black. Possibly only of the other filters will work, but `ShaderFilter` should definitely do the job (you write your own shader, so you can essentially do what you want). I don't have any real experience with filters, so I can't tell you how they work, but some googling should give you the necessary code

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#applyFilter()

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ShaderFilter.html

6) **Use photoshop (or equivalent)**

The easiest method; just edit your image to remove the black; much less hassle :)